# Inserting Column Name into a Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to insert column names from one table as data into another in SQL Server. This is the query I'm using:

```
insert into TableB (Name)
select COLUMN_NAME
from information_schema.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = 'TableA'
```

This returns zero rows. I have tried without specifying a TABLE_NAME, and also tried specifying the TABLE_SCHEMA. These both give results, but are not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Do you see the values you'd expect when you just run:  `SELECT COLUMN_NAME,TABLE_NAME
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS`?

Comment: @GoatCO The values I expect are there, as well as many that I do not want to insert.

Comment: And when you add the `WHERE` criteria with the table name from those results you get nothing?

Answer (score 3):

I can't see any issue with the SQL-code you provided.

**More troubleshooting:**

**1)** If you query:

```
select COLUMN_NAME
from information_schema.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = 'TableA'
```

**Do you get any results?**

**2)** If you try this INSERT, **is it working?**

```
INSERT INTO Table_1 (Name)
Select 'Name1'
```

**3)** If you select these columns, **do you see the TABLE_NAME in the list?**

```
Select DISTINCT(TABLE_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
```

---

Your sql-code worked well for me with AdventureWorks-DB from Microsoft (`Table_1` is an empty table with column name):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table_1 (Name)
Select COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
where TABLE_NAME = 'ProductInventory'

select * from table_1
```

**Output:**

```
ProductID
LocationID
Shelf
Bin
Quantity
rowguid
ModifiedDate
```

Comment: I'm running the select portion before trying to insert, and it returns 0 rows. The insert works. The TABLE_NAME is not in the list, it seems the problem was that the the table I was searching for is in a different database on the server. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be working as far as I can tell, that said, I always use sys.columns and sys.tables for these queries, try:

```
SELECT c.name ColumnName
FROM sys.columns c 
JOIN sys.tables t 
    ON c.object_id = t.object_id 
WHERE t.name = 'TableA'
```